Creating bootable USB for Atom based CPU and EXT4/BTRFS filesystem
Looking to create a ubuntu USB bootable.
YUMI and Rufus dont give the ability to setup the USB as EXT4/BTRFS which the Atom core needs.  I can use YUMI / rufus to create an already built 14.04.Ext4.img, however thats already built.
What i would like to do is run a newer flavour of ubuntu as bootable, but normal Ubuntu.com images are i386 or AMD.
Can anyone advise how to cook a atom based image to enable me to create a usable USB, using a normal i386 image doesnt result in booting, but the ext or btrfs works.

How old or model? "Intel Atom is a line of IA-32 and x86-64 instruction set ultra-low-voltage processors by Intel Corporation"  Ubuntu does not have 32 bit anymode and only current versions are supported here.  If newer you use the standard FAT32 installer with 64 bit AMD image as that is also Intel. If you want full install on USB, you have to have two USB flash drives, one FAT32 as installer & another to install into.

CPU is an Atom single core z520 1.3ghz. I built a Ubuntu 18.04 image from Ubuntu.com via Rufus it didn’t boot, yet a 14.04.ext.img when used via Rufus works.
